# Use image height() to set another element's margin

Tags: jquery, height

I am trying to make the top margin of one DIV equal to another elements height.

I can't get it to work in Chrome. Seems fine in FF and IE9.

I'm using height() to get the height of an image.

I am then subtracting that value from my top margin of another DIV

```
var GalleryImgHeight = $("#container #gallery img").height();
$("#content_container").css("margin-top", - GalleryImgHeight);

<div id="container">
<div id="gallery"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div id="content_container">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer.......</div>
</div>
```

I have this same code inside a resize function, so that it recalculates if they resize the browser.

For Chrome, it only works on resize. I'm guessing that the initial function is getting the height before the image is loaded.

I'm not getting any errors.

Should I try to preload the image?

Here's the complete code: http://troythibodeaux.com/temp/webdev/

My reasons for this is to get one DIV to stack on top of the other. Both DIVs are relatively placed, because the bottom DIV's width is 100%, so its dimensions will depend on the browser size. Tell me if I'm wrong, but I can't set the top DIV's position to absolute because I want it to be centered in the browser. So I couldn't really set the "left" attribute to a static value.

Mabye I took the wrong approach, but would love to hear another take on it.

Answer (score 0):

Great answer by Gordan but needs a change to the code to make the following line work:

```
var origMarginTop = $("#content_container").css("margin-top");
```

as it returns a string of the full css value ie. "10px". Clearly you can't take a pure number from 10px, you need it to be just 10. (10px-180 for example won't work, 10-180 will)

to get this to work I would suggest the following few lines (1 line added, 3rd line changed):

```
var marginTopString = origMarginTop.slice(0, -2);

if (GalleryImgHeight !== 0) {
$("#content_container").css("margin-top", marginTopString - GalleryImgHeight);
```

this modification to the code works fine for me.